# YouTube API v3 stopped returning status.publishAt

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

When I request the [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) (using the official PHP library) example:

```
$youtube->videos->listVideos($ytVideoID, "snippet, contentDetails, status");
```

the API stopped returning [status.publishAt](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.publishAt) couple months ago.

I am getting only this now:

```
[status] => Array
(
    [uploadStatus] => processed
    [privacyStatus] => private
    [license] => youtube
    [embeddable] => 1
    [publicStatsViewable] => 1
)
```

I need the response to look something like this:

```
[status] => Array
(
    [publishAt] => '2015-07-15T22:45:00'
    [uploadStatus] => processed
    [privacyStatus] => private
    [license] => youtube
    [embeddable] => 1
    [publicStatsViewable] => 1
)
```

I did not change anything in my code, the API just stopped returning the **publishAt** parameter one day. I did not managed to find any reference to any change in the API.

All the videos I am trying to load, have status: scheduled (private), so the publishAt parameter should be there.

Comment: So you're saying you can no longer get `publishAt` data for your scheduled videos that haven't yet been published? Does this still happen when you use the API explorer?

Comment: @not_a_bot Yes, it still doesn't return `publishAt` even in API explorer.

Comment: I think it's a bug then. You can check if there's ticket for it on the [YouTube issue tracer](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list) and submit it if there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

Reported this internally. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7447

I will update with solution.